# SublimeLinter not recognize "jest/globals" env

Tags: react-native, jestjs, sublimetext3, eslint, sublimelinter

SublimeLinter-Eslint not working after a fresh install of react-native project.

`shell$ react-native init MyProject`

Error is "Environment key "jest/globals" is unknown"

Running eslint (comand line) not fired any error.

`shell$ eslint App.js`

Also by Using "Eslint" package (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ESLint)

But the package "SublimeLinter-eslint" throw this error 
"Environment key "jest/globals" is unknown"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's works.
Need to downgrade eslint to version 5

Version 6 is incompatible with this plugin

see https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-eslint/issues/279